# Refreshing image in Div which only changes file contents, not name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a backend which updates an image file and sends the filename back to the front-end:

```
$('#giffinal').html(ResponseGo);
```

Now when I update my image the second time via the backend, the code in the `div` in the front-end stays exactly the same, so the browser doesn't update the image.

Is it possible to show the new image without the page reload or something?

Comment: Probably caching, why don't you show the relevant code

Comment: yes... $.ajax is what you need.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a timestamp after the image name to fool browser cache:

```
image.jpg?ts=[timestamp]
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I don't know if its the best solution but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, probably your image is cached.

Change the address, e.g. every time add to the address as a useless parameter current timestamp:

```
var url = "http://.../...?myparamIneed=...&uselessparameter=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

this will prevent the caching